# FastAPI - implement pause/resume/abort task API

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

I wish to implement an API that utilize asyncio events in order to pause/resume a task.
The API will support the following methods:

- run
- pause
- resume
- abort

I've started to play a bit and currently the main problem is happening when invoking the resume endpoint.
It seems that in that scenario the task was already finished with the following exception:

> RuntimeError("Task <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<TaskManager.async_task() running at>> got Future  attached to a different loop")

In order to reproduce the issue:

- Run the server
- Start a task using the run endpoint
- Pause the task using the pause endpoint
- Resume the task using the resume endpoint

I've used the following code:

```
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()


class TaskManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._pause_event = asyncio.Event()
        self._task_running = False
        self._current_task = None

    async def async_task(self):
        while True:
            await self._pause_event.wait()
            print("Async Task is running...")
            # Simulate some asynchronous work
            await asyncio.sleep(2)

    async def start_task(self):
        if not self._task_running:
            self._task_running = True
            self._pause_event.set()
            self._current_task = asyncio.create_task(self.async_task())
            print("Task started.")
        else:
            print("Task is already running.")

    async def pause_task(self):
        self._task_running = False
        self._pause_event.clear()
        print("Task paused.")

    async def resume_task(self):
        self._task_running = True
        self._pause_event.set()
        print("Task resumed.")

    async def abort_task(self):
        self._task_running = False
        self._pause_event.set()
        self._current_task.cancel()
        print("Task aborted.")


# Create the TaskManager instance
task_manager = TaskManager()


@app.post("/run")
async def run_background_task():
    await task_manager.start_task()
    return {"message": "Task started."}


@app.post("/pause")
async def pause_background_task():
    await task_manager.pause_task()
    return {"message": "Task paused."}


@app.post("/resume")
async def resume_background_task():
    await task_manager.resume_task()
    return {"message": "Task resumed."}


@app.post("/abort")
async def abort_background_task():
    await task_manager.abort_task()
    return {"message": "Task aborted."}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5049)
```

- Please ignore the abort endpoint, I didn't finish with it yet